# React Native, How to run task in background mode?

Tags: react-native

I just take some days to research about run task in background mode 
And figure out "react-native-background-fetch" is a package do that, and bellow is result that I understand that package when the background task will be run:

**In Android**

when app open: run
when app minimize: run
when lock screen: run
when restart phone: stop

**In IOS**

when app open: run
when restart phone: stop 
when app minimize or when lock screen: can not predict when task wil be run, maybe when plug into power

In android I can run a task every 5 minutes
but iOS, I just can run task for sometimes
how can I resolve for ios to run more frequently?

Regard,

Comment: You can create a [native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) where u will run the background task